# Realm Search in table view, Swift 3

Tags: swift, cocoapods, realm, swift3

I am developing an app where I use realm to store my data and view it using table views. And before updating my project to Swift 3 I used RealmSearchController to search my realm data in the table view. But at the moment I can't find if this is still supported by Realm 1.1.0? Do anyone know any better way to allow the users search the data?

Thank you

Comment: RealmSearchController is built by an individual programmer and is not an official Realm product. If you want Swift 3 support you will need to ask the developer to update his project or update the code and file a pull request at his GitHub page (https://github.com/bigfish24/ABFRealmSearchViewController). Otherwise, you will need to roll your own.